# Quadratic problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, quadratics

NASA launches a rocket at $t = 0$ seconds. Its height, in meters above sea-level, as a function of time is given by $h(t) = -4.9t^2 + 37 t + 101$.

Assuming that the rocket will splash down into the ocean, at what time does splashdown occur?

How high above sea-level does the rocket get at its peak?

#### Progress

I figured that it will splash down after 9.68032 seconds. I don't know how to find it's peak though.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  What have you tried thus far?

Comment: I figured that it will splash down after 9.68032 seconds, I don't know how to find it's peak though.

Comment: Did you use the Quadratic Formula $$t = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$ to find when it will splash down?

Comment: louie mcconnell helped me answer thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The x-coordinate of the vertex (peak) of any quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ is $\frac{-b}{2a}$. By inputting this value into your function, you can find the y-coordinate of the vertex (peak)

Comment: Thank's totally forgot -b/2a I got the correct answer:170.819